# Use a label to display the total of a listbox

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

Just a simple question, how do i make a label display the sum all values that have been entered into a textbox or listbox. Is there a way to do this without an array?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a label.
2. Create a method, which returns the sum of all values you have entered.
3. Assign the label's value to the result of the method.